# Using gravity's force to do work?

Tags: forces, gravity, energy, power

Since gravity is everywhere and we don't need to do anything to feel it and interact with gravity,  can we somehow extract the gravity force to do work and power machines?

For example,  we've nuclear energy that produces electricity.  Would it be possible to somehow have two bodies generate electricity purely on the gravitational attraction force between them?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216802/

Answer (score 1):

Hydraulic barrages and all water turbines are exactly doing that (getting either electricity or mechanic power).

In practice Earth gravity induces the notion of potential energy related to the altitude of a mass. By lowering the altitude, you can convert potential energy in kinetics energy or others.

Comment: They seem to convert water's momentum into energy, no? What I mean is extracting energy purely based on gravitational force `F = G*m1*m2/r^2`. Like when you've two big rocks, they attract each other. Can't we somehow make them do work as well while they keep attracting?

Comment: In the barrage lake, water was at rest. Gravity caused the momentum.

Comment: @bodacydo - the energy extracted comes from gravitational potential energy - the water head pressure is caused by gravity. That lets there be net momentum in the flowing water.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET this is a great start to a response --- but it could be improved by explaining the underlying concepts, and how those examples are using gravity / gravitational-energy.

Comment: @bodacydo: note that the gravity force between 2 rocks is ultra small, that's why one of the 2 rocks is better be Earth :-) . Anyway you could put an hydraulic jack or gear between the 2 rocks (or between rock and Earth) and get a bit of energy with that. But once in contact, it's finished. And to bring the rock away again require energy: you loose what you gained. :-)

Comment: @bodacydo - "Can't we somehow make them do work as well while they keep attracting?"  No.  Work was already done when the attractive forces between the masses moved the masses together. Once the masses are together, an additional force must be applied to separate the masses.  Evaporating water (with & without solar power), allowing it to rise as high as possible, then using nature to condense it so that we can store it for a waterfall+turbine is about as good as I can imagine at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

At huge scale, there is another way to get energy from gravity: letting a huge mass of gaz/dust/rocks collapsing by self-gravity into a star or a planet. This cause huge heating, sometime light, and for star, nuclear reactions, all that can be used for work.